# App width is not fit to window if it is opened in IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

We have a third party web application which needs to be integrated into our web portal. We used iframe approach to integrate that. It would look like:

[image: this]

Iframe got some scrolls. So I got to inspect their code and found that they kept some static width to body around `1280px` where the iframe can't afford since its width is less than that.

But the interesting thing here is, when the third party app is run in an iPad (without iframe, directly in browser address bar), there are no scrolls and the app got fit into the `ipad` window size. I believe iPad browser's width is less than `1280px`(not really sure). So I wonder, how could the app got fit into window without any scrolls. They are not doing any device based width settings. I inspected the code in iPad and saw that `body` is set to `1280px`.

So the question here is, how does it work properly in iPad and how to avoid scrolls in desktop if app is run in iframe?

Comment: If you need embed and make an iframe fit into your own application, I suggest you trying [this library](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer)

Comment: @FrancescoPezzella As per the doc : "The second file (iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js) is a native JavaScript file that needs placing in the page contained within your iFrame", I don't have any control on the third party web app. I wonder how can it be achieved!!

Comment: The question about the ipad is that the ipad fits the page to the screen and lets you zoom.  You really won't find a "great" solution if you don't have access to css or js within the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
  width: 1530px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.rightpane {
  margin-left: 250px;
  border: none;
  width: 1280px;
  height: 100%;
}
.leftnav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="leftnav">
  left nav here
  </div>
<iframe class="rightpane" src="http://example.com/" />
```

The most straightforward solution is to just set the iframe width to 1280px.  On an ipad it will show the whole page correctly being zoomed out.

Comment: if `1530px` width is set to `html,body` , now browser gets scroll in desktop.

Comment: yep, there is not a perfect solution to this issue.  only real solution would involve having control to put css or javascript inside the iframe.